# javascript to replace a value has unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input element that has a `value="Go"`, the element's `id` is `#btnSearchBox`, I'm trying to replace "Go" with a fontawesome icon. When using dev tools if I manually replace the value "Go" with `&#xf002` ,the code for search, and manually add fa fa-search to the class I get the result I want. But when I try to implement this with JavaScript it replaces the value and adds the class but instead of the icon showing up I get the actual string `&#xf002`.

This is the JavaScript I'm using to add a class and replace the value.

```
document.getElementById('btnSearchBox').value = '&#xf002';
var search = document.getElementById("btnSearchBox");
search.className += " fa fa-search";
```

I think it has something to do with the `&` but I'm not sure what can be done about it. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Here is a copy of the element from the inspector (as is without the JavaScript).

```
<input id="btnSearchBox" name="btnSearchBox" type="submit" class="SearchBox1 ThemeButton GoThemeButton SearchGoThemeButton btn btn-default" value="Go" data-key="ThemeButton_Go_Search_string" onclick="return window.btnQuickAddToCart_onclick ? btnQuickAddToCart_onclick() : false;" \="">
```

I cannot actually access the code otherwise id just manually add it. It's a stupid americommerce merge code for there searchbox.

Comment: Please show us the html code

Comment: The element is a text input field?

Comment: Is the input a `button`?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `&#xf002` code as the value, just setting the class to `fa fa-search` should work.

Comment: I hope you are running that script after the fontawesome done loading.

Comment: font awesome is called in the head tags, this code is being added to the bottom of the body so it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unicode character in javascript has format `\uXXXX`, so change `'&#xf002'` to `'\uf002'`

```js
document.getElementById('btnSearchBox').value = '\uf002';
var search = document.getElementById("btnSearchBox");
search.className += " fa";
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<input id="btnSearchBox" name="btnSearchBox" type="submit" class="SearchBox1 ThemeButton GoThemeButton SearchGoThemeButton btn btn-default" value="Go" data-key="ThemeButton_Go_Search_string" onclick="return window.btnQuickAddToCart_onclick ? btnQuickAddToCart_onclick() : false;" \="">
```

Comment: @robothead I've changed my code snippet to exactly reflect your code and it works as expected. The problem must be elsewhere.